# read external coordinates of a converged force directed graph in d3.js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using Mike Bostock's example here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

The html was modified to export the nodes and links in a json file. Unfortunately I cannot upload the whole file but here are some example lines:

```
{"nodes":[
{"id":"Myriel","group":1,"index":0,"x":791.0400812247225, "y":533.3621312414037,vy":-2.3537711995332984,"vx":-4.361299434636218},
{"id":"Napoleon","group":1,"index":1,"x":761.1221752922569, "y":563.7517203508193,"vy":-2.3317798484016428,"vx":-4.346736342960801},
.
.
.
"links":[{
  "source":
    {"id":"Napoleon","group":1,"index":1,"x":761.1221752922569, "y":563.7517203508193,"vy":-2.3317798484016428,"vx":-4.346736342960801},
  "target":
    {"id":"Myriel","group":1,"index":0,"x":791.0400812247225, "y":533.3621312414037,"vy":-2.3537711995332984,"vx":-4.361299434636218},
  "value":1,"index":0},
    .
    .
    .
```

What I would like to do is read the nodes and links in another html file and just display it.

I thought this should be rather straight forward by replacing the input file miserables.json file with xy_miserables.json. The first thing I noted is that the nodes are not connected to the links, the second thing was that the nodes drifted apart but the links remained fixed. I was able to change the simulation parameters so the nodes stay close to their original position. But how am I going to connect the links to their nodes?
Here is the html content:

```
<script>
 var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }));
    //.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    //.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("./xy_miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
   if (error) throw error;

   link = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

   node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
        .attr("x", function(d) {return d.x})
        .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y});

console.log(graph.links)

simulation.force("link")
  .links(graph.links);

simulation
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .on("tick", ticked);

 function ticked() {
   link
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

   node
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
 }
});
</script>
```

I confirmed that the links have the proper source ids and target ids defined. I compared the link info with the original data and it seems fine.
What am I forgetting here?
[image]

Thank you very much in advance,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I realized that the issue lies with my exported xyz file I am trying to read in. I started out with the miserables.json file and added systematically node and link properties. As it turns out none of the link properties are required. This is the final solution to my json file:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "1", "property1": "propert1", "property2": "property2", "property3": "property3", "x": "999.772419601515",  "y": "597.0467800520148",  "vx": "0",  "vy": "0",  "fx": "999.772419601515",  "fy": "597.0467800520148"},
    {"id": "2", "property1": "propert1", "property2": "property2", "property3": "property3", "x": "999.772419601515",  "y": "597.0467800520148",  "vx": "0",  "vy": "0",  "fx": "999.772419601515",  "fy": "597.0467800520148"},....],
"links": [
    {"source": "1", "target": "2, "value": 1},
    {"source": "1", "target": "3", "value": 1},....]
}
```

Now my links are connected to the nodes.
Cheers,
Markus